# Rotate multiple keyframes at once?

Tags: keyframes, timeline, select

How can I select multiple keyframes and add rotation to all of them at once?

Comment: do you want to rotate an object?

Comment: In the "Graph Editor". https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/graph_editor/introduction.html